# Как переименовать атрибут в MongoRecord?

Tags: yii2, mongodb

Пишу скрипт для миграции. Необходимо переименовать элемент коллекции(для сохранения старых данных, и проверки обращений к ним)

```
class NativeParams extends ActiveRecord {

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function collectionName() {
        return 'params';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributes() {
        return [
            '_id', 'input_data', 'old_input_data'
        ];
    }
}
```

Пробую так

```
$allParams = NativeParams::find()->all();

foreach ($allParams as $model) {
    $model->old_input_data = $model->input_data;
    //$model->input_data = null;
    unset($model->input_data);
    $model->save();
}
```

Элемент копируется. Но в базе остаётся старая копия. Как его полностью удалить? Пробовал присвоить ему NULL, но мне необходимо именно удалить его из базы а не присвоить другое значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось намного проще

```
NativeParams::getCollection()->update([], [
    '$rename' => [
        'input_data' => 'old_input_data'
    ]
]);
```